# datagrid column button command (MVVM)

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

I have the following

```
<ResourceDictionary 

xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication1.ViewModels.Controls"> 

<DataTemplate DataType="vm:CVItemVM" x:Key="viewmodel">
```

..........

```
                    <sdk:DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="820" MaxColumnWidth="395" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Publications}" Visibility="{Binding Path=Publications.Count, Converter={StaticResource ConverterVisibility2_1}}">
                        <sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridColumnHeader">
                                <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold" />                                     
                            </Style>
                        </sdk:DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
                        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Title" Binding="{Binding Path=Title}"  CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Author" Binding="{Binding Path=Author}" CanUserResize="False" IsReadOnly="True"  />
                            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="">                                    
                                <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />                                            
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>                                
                        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

The problem I'm facing is that

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Does not trigger the command which is bind to.

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Publications}"
```

refers to the following (in the viewmodel)

```
public ObservableCollection<PublicationVM> Publications
```

The same viewmodel exposes

```
public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; set; }
```

Comment: have your tried RelativeSource Binding? btw you should write what your real problem is.

Answer (score 8):

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}" Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

this code trying to access `DeleteCommand` property from PublicationVM object. if such property defined there, it should work (if property not `null` ofc.).
if `DeleteCommand` defined in the same VM where

```
public ObservableCollection<PublicationVM> Publications
```

then u should use `RelativeSource` to your VM, for example:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=Id}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
```

where `UserControl` - type of your control where `DataContext` = YourViewModel

Comment: After spending almost a day on this the RelativeSource suggestion finally worked for me.